# Sending a templated function as an argument to a templated function in D

Tags: templates, d, dmd

I'm trying to send D's `sort` function as a template argument to the `pipe` function. When I use `sort` without template arguments it works:

```
import std.stdio,std.algorithm,std.functional;

void main()
{
    auto arr=pipe!(sort)([1,3,2]);
    writeln(arr);
}
```

However, when I try to use `sort` with a template argument:

```
import std.stdio,std.algorithm,std.functional;

void main()
{
    auto arr=pipe!(sort!"b<a")([1,3,2]);
    writeln(arr);
}
```

I get an error - `main.d(5): Error: template instance sort!("b<a") sort!("b<a") does not match template declaration sort(alias less = "a < b",SwapStrategy ss = SwapStrategy.unstable,Range)`

Why does it happen? `sort!"b<a"` works on it's own, and it has the same arguments and return types as `sort`, so why does `pipe` accept `sort` but not `sort!"b<a"`? And is there a correct syntax for what I try to do?

**UPDATE**

OK, I've tried to wrap the `sort` function. The following code works:

```
import std.stdio,std.algorithm,std.functional,std.array;

template mysort(string comparer)
{
    auto mysort(T)(T source)
    {
        sort!comparer(source);
        return source;
    }
}

void main()
{
    auto arr=pipe!(mysort!"b<a")([1,3,2]);
    writeln(arr);
}
```

So why doesn't the original version work? is this because of the extra template parameters `sort` takes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's because of the extra template parameters — specifically the `Range` parameter. The problem can be reduced to

```
size_t sort2(alias f, Range)(Range range)
{
    return 0;
}
alias sort2!"b<a" u;
```

The instantiation `sort!"b<a"` will fail because the Range is not determined. The function call `sort2!"b<a"([1,2,3])` works because the parameter `[1,2,3]` can tell the compiler the type Range is `int[]`. This is known as "implicit function template instantiation (IFTI)". But IFTI only works when it is used as a function. In your use case, `sort!"b<a"` is instantiated without providing all parameters, thus the error.

This can be fixed by making the input a function literal, which is just similar to your `mysort` solution:

```
 auto arr = pipe!(x => sort!"b<a"(x))([1,3,2]);
```

Or you could provide all required template parameters. This makes the code very unreadable though.

```
auto arr = pipe!(sort!("b<a", SwapStrategy.unstable, int[]))([1,3,2]);
```

Comment: I see... I figured the `pipe` template, that implicitly get's the type of the argument as a template parameter, should pass that parameter to the first piped function, but I see that's not the case.

Comment: @IdanArye: `pipe` can never do that, because one could separate it from the argument (`alias pipe!(f) piped;` and then many lines later `piped([1,2,3]);`)

Comment: Shouldn't `alias`ing like that make `piped` a templated function itself?